# PHP PREG_MATCH 2 criterias

Tags: php, regex

How can I do this easily:

```
$ipp='/(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)([\s\:\-]+[0-9]{2,5})/'; // IP Address

preg_match_all($ipp, $line, $matches);
```

This matches ip:port in multiple formats. I want to define a second criteria like you would do it at a shell script with (A && B) that only match if the port number is NOT "143" exactly. In the future I would might like to extend this with additional ports like "993", "995" etc.

Thanks

Comment: Provide some example inputs with expected output.

Comment: like return true if both statement are true? if prge_match === true and !143 === true? is that it?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have to do a task like that, I create a custom function for it so I could modify it, add - remove parameters, if it needs more functions, I create an object. in that case I will just create a function for that tsak.

```
    function check($ip, $against){
        $ipChecked = false;
        $againstChecked = false;
        //pregmatch statement with the ip, if true, the $ipChecked = true;
        //pregmatch $against with the ip, if false then $againstChecked = true;
        if ($ipchecked === true && $againstChecked===true)
             return true;
        else
             return false;
    }
```

Feel free to customise that function to add any parameter you want
then use it like this:

```
$ip = '145.254.021';
$against ='143';
$check = check($ip, $against);
if($check === true){
     //Insert code here...
}
```

Did I understood your question well?